# Grails - creating multiple nested objects inside single form

Tags: grails

I have simply hierarchy.

```
class Atom { String value}

class Unit { 
    List atoms
    static hasMany = [ atoms:Atom ] 
    String name
}

class Block {
    List unitss 
    static hasMany = [ units:Unit ] 
    String name
}
```

Let's say I want to create one block which contains two units with two atoms each.
So, first, I create four atoms in atom form. Then, I create two units, and select previously created atoms. In the end, I create block and select previously created units. It isn't convenient, so I want to move all creation logic in single form. I used approach from this article http://www.2paths.com/2009/10/01/one-to-many-relationships-in-grails-forms/

In short, I added method in class Block:

```
def getExpandableUnitList() {
    return LazyList.decorate(units,FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Unit.class))
}
```

Also, I added button which call js function:

```
var unitCount = ${blockInstance?.units.size()} + 0;
function addUnit()
{
    var htmlId = "unit" + unitCount;
    var deleteIcon = "${resource(dir:'images/skin', file:'database_delete.png')}";
    var templateHtml = "<div id='" + htmlId + "' name='" + htmlId + "'>\n";
    templateHtml += "Unit "+ (unitCount + 1) + "\n";
    templateHtml += "<input type='hidden' id='expandableUnitList[" + unitCount + "].name' name='expandableUnitList[" + unitCount + "].name' />\n";
    templateHtml += "<span onClick='$(\"#" + htmlId + "\").remove();'><img src='" + deleteIcon + "' /></span>\n";
    templateHtml += "</div>\n";
    $("#UnitList").append(templateHtml);
    unitCount++;
}
```

Now, I can create block with units in one form(see the image below, sorry for bad form design)

[Form 1 http://imageshack.us/a/img833/8775/screenshotfrom201210241.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img833/8775/screenshotfrom201210241.png)

However, this form isn't convenient too - we can't add atoms to units.

So, I added lazylist to unit class, and added another button with almost the same js code.
Now, I've got this:

[Form 2 http://imageshack.us/a/img31/8775/screenshotfrom201210241.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img31/8775/screenshotfrom201210241.png)

However, when I creating this form - it doesn't save my atoms. It is expected behaviour, because our unit's lazy list doesn't know about atom's lazy list. And I don't know how to manage that. The only thing I've tried - the below code, but it doesn't work.

```
templateHtml += "<input type='hidden' id='expandableBlockList[" + blockId + "].add(expandableUnitList[" + unitCount + "].name)' name='expandableBlockList[0].add(expandableUnitList[" + unitCount + "].name)' />\n";
```

So. my question is - how to create multiple nested objects in single form?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Grails documentation - specifically the section on [Gorm cascading behavior](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#cascades), it explains what you are looking for.

*... Whether it is a one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many, **defining belongsTo will result in updates cascading from the owning class to its dependant** (the other side of the relationship), and for many-/one-to-one and one-to-many relationships deletes will also cascade.*

*If you **do not define belongsTo then no cascades will happen and you will have to manually save each object** (except in the case of the one-to-many, in which case saves will cascade automatically if a new instance is in a hasMany collection).*

Edit:

BTW - not sure if this is a typo, but your Block definition does not contain any Units

I was quick to submit an answer and probably should have given it more thought - it sounds like your issue is more on the form side vs the domain definition. Currently as your domain is defined, you **should** be able to create an Atom and it's relationship with Unit when you create a Unit. Here's a really simple form to illustrate what you need to do in terms of how to define the inputs.

```
<form ...
  Unit: <input type="text" name="name" value="" /> 
  Atom 1: <input type="text" name="atoms[0].value" value="" />
  Atom 2: <input type="text" name="atoms[1].value" value="" />
 ...
</form>
```

The size of the atoms collection is hard-coded here for an example, but in a more scalable solution you would define them dynamically. So on submission, this would create the Unit, and it's 2 Atoms.

Edit:
Have you tried something like this:

```
Block: <g:textField name="name" value=""/>
<br />
Unit 1: <g:textField name="units[0].name" value=""/> atoms:
<g:textField name="units[0].atoms[0].value" value=""/>
<g:textField name="units[0].atoms[1].value" value=""/>
<br />
Unit 2: <g:textField name="units[0].name" value=""/> atoms:
<g:textField name="units[0].atoms[0].value" value=""/>
<g:textField name="units[0].atoms[1].value" value=""/>
```