# Multiple Nested Domains Over Multiple Forms in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, nested-forms

I am new to grails and trying to build a small application which has some one to many relationships and I am stuck.

So there are three domain classes Artist, Album and Song.  The intention is a doubly nested 1->m relationship:

An Artist can have many Albums and an Album can have many songs.

```
class Artist {

    List albums = new ArrayList()

    static hasMany = [albums: Album]

    String artistName

    static mapping = {
        albums cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
    }
}

    class Album {

    String albumName
    String albumDescr

    static belongsTo = [artist: Artist]

    List songs = new ArrayList()
    static hasMany = [songs: Song]

    boolean deleted
    static transients = [ 'deleted' ]


     static mapping = {

         songs cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
    }
}

    class Song{

    Album album
    static belongsTo = [album: Album]
    String songName
    Integer trackNumber

    boolean deleted
    static transients = [ 'deleted' ]
}
```

I would like to use a series of forms to handle the input of data.  In the first view an Artist would be created with any associated Albums.  This view would be similar to the 
views described here: http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/

On submission of the form the Artist and associated Albums would be saved (something like the following)

```
 def artist = new Artist(params)
 artistGroup.save()
```

**Here is the part I need help with...**

The next view would display the Albums created with the previous view and prompt the user to add the Song information for each.  Upon submission of this form
the Songs would be saved.

I was thinking I would pass the saved albums in flash scope

```
 flash.myAlbums = artist.albums
```

so they could be displayed in the second view.  However, showing the name of the album is only part of the story, as we will need the Album.id in order to save each of the 
Songs (and correctly associate its Album).  How can this ID be passed effectively into the second view so that it can be used to save each Song correctly upon submission of the second form?  I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046539/grails-creating-multiple-nested-objects-inside-single-form) and it does relate but it does not try to break up saving the data into multiple view.

I hope this question makes some sense and I appreciate any feedback...including alternate approaches for this.

Answer (score 0):

In you album controller's save() method, render the second view with params like:

```
Class AlbumController {
    ......
    def save() {
        def artist = new Artist(params)
        artist.save()                       //the original artistGroup.save() won't work
        params.albumsSelected.each{album->           //for instance, you can pass all the album_id related to the artist in this parameter
            def albumInstance = Album.get(album)
            artist.addToAlbums(albumInstance)
        }
        render(view:'showAlbum', params:[albums:artist.albums])
    }

    def addSong() {
        def albumSelected = Album.get(params.album)
        def songToAdd = Song.findBySongName(params.songName)
        albumSelected.addToSongs(songToAdd)
        ......
    }
```

**showAlbum.gsp:**

```
...
<g:form name="addSong" action="addSong">
    <g:select name="album"
          from="${albums}"
          optionKey="id"
          optionValue="albumName" />
    <g:textField name="songName"/>
    <g:submitButton name="add" value="Add To Album" />
</g:form>
...
```

And you also need to remove duplicated property definition in your domain class:

```
 class Song{
 //    Album album    is not needed when there is a 'belongsTo' definition
     static belongsTo = [album: Album]
     ...
}
```

Comment: Jinzhao- Thank you for the explanation.  Does the save() function have to be in the Album controller?  Could this logic be stored in a separate controller (not one tied to a domain)?  I have a controller called registerartist which I was hoping to use but I notice when I pass the params as a model above (params:[albums:artist.albums]) nothing seems to get passed.  Thank you again for taking the time to help me out here...much appreciated!

Comment: [save()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) is a method shipped with Grails. You may need to go through the [Grails tutorials](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication) to learn the basic first.